# how to connect microsoft sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I try to connect Microsoft sql server 2008 r2  my local computer show error message

[This error message are show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoBxT.png)

please any solution ...

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't have a lot of details. Such as how are you trying to connect currently? In the absence of that, I offer this...

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Perhaps you can find what you need there.

Noel